# Using Console application to perform SharePoint tasks Not working in Cloudshare

Tags: windows

I need to create a unit testing module using Console application that communicates with SharePoint. I add the refernces and I write the code, but once I hit F5, the program breaks and I get error messages that SPSite does not exist in the current context.

I am doing this in Cloudshare. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Are you running the console application on the server that SharePoint is running?

Comment: I am accessing the SharePoint server from CloudShare. Everything is on CloudShare

Comment: Which of the SharePoint machine templates are you useing? Could be a template issue? Is the web application and site collection exists?